# Can we find the minimal polynomial of $a+1/a$ from the minimal polynomial of $a$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a$ be an algebraic number(over the rationals). Then we may find the minimal polynomial of $1/a$ by reversing the order of coefficients in the minimal polynomial of $a$. Can we find the minimal polynomial of $a+1/a$ by using a similar method? Obviously we know it's algebraic, but I want to see something constructive.

Comment: Consider that, if $\zeta$ is a primitive third root of unity, then $\zeta + \frac{1}{\zeta}=-1$. The minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $\zeta^3-1$, but the minimal polynomial of $-1$ is $z+1$ - so I'll bet Robert Israel's answer is the best you'll get, given that reduction might happen. (Whereas, to contract, the algebraic degree of $\zeta$ and $\frac{1}{\zeta}$ are equal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course we're assuming $a \ne 0$.
Let $M$ be the companion matrix of the minimal polynomial of $a$.  Then
$a + 1/a$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $M + M^{-1}$.   This might not be irreducible, so the minimal polynomial of $a + 1/a$ is one of its factors.